# Strategy.exit() only works on the first trade (PineScript)

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance

i don't know if anyone else is experiencing this bug but a few hours ago I checked my `strategy results` in tradingview and my saw there is only one trade made. before that there almost 100 trades in backtesting. i found out that `strategy.exit()` is working for first trade for some reason and it doesn't close other trades. here's a dummy strategy:

```
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)
longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
limit = strategy.position_avg_price*(1.01)
stop =strategy.position_avg_price*(0.99)
strategy.exit(id = "My Long Entry Id",limit = limit*(1.01),stop =  stop)
```

and the results:

[image]

Only these two trades were started, and the second one isn't close yet after 9 days.Is it just me or other people are having the same problem? Is there any way around this?

Comment: Your dummy code is working just fine, which chart/pair is that and which time frame?

Comment: it seems tradingview fixed the issue, im closing the thread.